# static template constexpr error

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, constexpr

Hi all I have the following class : "Verification.h"

---

```
#ifndef VERIFICATION_H
#define VERIFICATION_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <dlib/svm.h>
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;


class Verification
{
    public:
        Verification(std::string, std::vector<string>,const int);
        virtual ~Verification();
        void Verify();
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> groundTruth;
        std::string path;
        const int rows;

};

#endif // VERIFICATION_H
```

---

Verification.cpp

```
#include "Verification.h"

Verification::Verification(string p, std::vector<string> gt,const int r):path(p),groundTruth(gt),rows(r)
{

}

Verification::~Verification()
{
    //dtor
}

void Verification::Verify()
{
    //Load ground truth and build matrix
    typedef matrix<double, rows, 9> sample_type;
    typedef radial_basis_kernel<sample_type> kernel_type;


}
```

---

**Problem :** I am trying to initialize:

```
 typedef matrix<double, 9,1> sample_type;
```

But i am getting the following erros:

1. Verification.cpp|16|error: 'this' is not a constant expression|
2. Verification.cpp|16|note: in template argument for type 'long int' |
3. Verification.cpp|16|error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token|

How can i solve it?

Thank you.

---

An edit based on the answer of MM:

```
  //Load ground truth and build matrix
    typedef matrix<double> data;
    data data_type;
    data_type.set_size(9,1);
```

Comment: You can't use a variable (`rows`) to instantiate a template.

Comment: You need a compile time constant instead of the variable `rows`

Comment: ok I found out that we can use a set_size() member function please can you see the edited question

Comment: `data`is defined to be a *type* now (`matrix<double>`), not an instance.

Comment: @Hulk I was looking for constexpr 
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-compile-time-processing-with-constexpr.html

is that what u mean?

Comment: That can help you if you know the dimension of your matrix at compile time, i.e. if it cannot change during runtime.

Comment: It should also be noted that radial_basis_kernel requires the samples to be column vectors.  So you can't use a rows by 9 matrix with radial_basis_kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable `rows` should be known in compile time.

You can make it `static constexpr` if you want use constant instead of a number, for example:

```
static constexpr int rows = 1;
```

```
typedef matrix<double> data;
```

It declared a new type called `data` with type `matrix<double>`, not a object. Try this:

```
typedef matrix<double> data_type;
data_type data;
data.set_size(rows,9);
```

Comment: So I can't use it at runtime?

Comment: @HaniGoc Pass 0 as the template argument `matrix< 0, 9 >` and pass `rows` as a runtime argument to the constructor.

Comment: yes @Potatoswatter I did this. It's a good solution. I eddited my question. I just have one last silly question please
Suppose i define a new type :
**typedef radial_basis_kernel<data> kernel_type;** afer having resized the matrix. the data in kernel_type will have the size of rows and 9 right?

Comment: @HaniGoc If you used such a typedef with the "dynamic" size of zero rows, it would not know about the `rows` variable, and the size of any `kernel_type` object would dynamically vary with its underlying matrix.

Comment: @Potatoswatter yes I get it, i get it. all what data_type is a **type**. I get it

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
typedef matrix<double> data;
```

Defines a type named `data` (which is a very poor name for a type).

Most likely you want to just remove the `typedef`:

```
matrix<double> data;
data.set_size(rows,9);
```